# Clarification Request about Declarative Transaction via XML configuration in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I am studying Spring Declarative Transaction via XML configuration reading this article:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/declarative_management.htm

I am only having some proble to understand well how AOP work in this case, in my **Beans.xml** configuration file I have:

```
   <tx:advice id="txAdvice"  transaction-manager="transactionManager">
      <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="create"/>
      </tx:attributes>
   </tx:advice>

   <aop:config>
      <aop:pointcut id="createOperation" 
      expression="execution(* com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate.create(..))"/>
      <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="createOperation"/>
   </aop:config>
```

So, what exactly means this configuration?

I think that work in the following way (but I am not sure):

The transaction semantics to apply are encapsulated in the  definition and I think that, in this case, simply specify that the **create()** method definied in the **StudentDAO** interface have to be a transactional behavior (is it right?)

Regarding the meaning of the content of **aop:config** tag I think that only ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution of com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate.create() method

Is it right? Or am I missing something?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Spring has very nice documentation, use it. :) Also for this particular use-case it provides an [example config](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-first-example) (very similar to yours) with lot's of comments explainig what the different parts exactly do.

Comment: I just read this paper and I want know if my personal interpretation is right...

Answer (score 2):

You are right,

`aop:pointcut` will find out all the joinpoints where advise should be applied, defined with `tx:advice`.

also `tx:advice` gives extra tags to filter out these join points using `tx:method` tags with method attribute.

In above mentioned example,

pointcut will find only one joinpoint, and `tx:advice` will filter out joinpoints with `tx:method`'s name attribute and apply specified configuration.In example default configuration values will be used.